# Add class for all same text

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have:

```
<a class="choice" data-name="i_can_a_test_1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="image.png" >
</a>
<a class="choice" data-name="i_can_a_test_2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="image2.png" >
</a>

<table>
<tr><td name="i_can_a_test_1" id="name_cards">i_can_a_test_1</td></tr>
<tr><td name="i_can_a_test_2" id="name_cards">i_can_a_test_2</td></tr>
<tr><td name="cant_a_test_1" id="name_cards">cant_a_test_2</td></tr>
</table>
```

But now I want: if same, add class for all `i_can_a_test_*`

```
$('body').on("click",".choice", function(){

    var same_text = $(this).data('name').slice(0,6);        
    var same = $( 'td[name^='+same_text+']' ).length;

     **if same, add class for all "i_can_a_test_*"**
 });
```

Do you know how I can do that? With each i think.

Comment: id should be unique. use class="name_cards" then $(".name_cards")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the attribute starts with selector.

Here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```js
$('body').on("click",".choice", function(){

  var same = $(this).data('name').slice(0,13);   
  $('td[name^=' + same + ']').addClass('myClass');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="choice" data-name="i_can_a_test_1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="image.png"/>
</a>
<a class="choice" data-name="i_can_a_test_2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="image2.png"/>
</a>

<table>
  <tr><td name="i_can_a_test_1">i_can_a_test_1</td></tr>
  <tr><td name="i_can_a_test_2">i_can_a_test_2</td></tr>
  <tr><td name="cant_a_test_1">cant_a_test_2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("*")].filter(e=>e.textContent.split("i_can_a_test_")[1]).forEach(e=>e.ClassName+=" someclass");
```

That does what youre asking for. However, this is bad style...

Answer (score 0):

After changing id="name_cards" to class:

```
$('body').on('click', '.choice', function(e) {
  var name = $(this).data('name').substr(0,6)
    , $cards = $('.name_cards')
    ;
  $cards
    .removeClass('red')
    .filter('[name^="'+name+'"]')
    .addClass('red')
    ;
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNGqEQ